# Как правильно организовать вывод поля, если оно находится в другой таблице?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Здравствуйте.

Имеется таблица отзывов, она содержит помимо тематических полей(комментарий, рейтинг) поле `user_id`. Но на front-end вывод `user_id` будет неудобен для пользователей, а хотелось бы выводить имя пользователя.

Но чтобы получить имя пользователя это к каждому отзыву нужен +1 запрос с получением информации пользователя по id. Таким образом на 5 отзывов +5 запросов. Мне кажется, это не самый лучший вариант. Возникает идея - хранить копию имени пользователя в таблице отзывов, но правильно ли это?

Каков вариант правильный в данной ситуации - запросы, или хранение копии имени пользователя? Либо есть какие-либо другие правильные варианты?

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Зачем Вам 5 запросов? Их может быть 1 (при использовании JOIN), либо 2, при получении отзывов и авторов по отдельности.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать join с таблицей user

```
JOIN user ON t_rating.user_id=user.id
```

и тогда в SELECT можно будет указывать поля из таблицы user

```
SELECT ..., user.name
```

Можно первым запросом собрать все user_id и сделать еще один запрос

```
SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE id IN (массив user_id)
```

а потом объединить результаты запросам средствами PHP